# Using glob to pull images in the correct rotation

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to rotate images in a directory. My issue is I can't get the correct path, if I put `$imageR` as the image source nothing comes through. My code is below:

```
foreach(glob('media/{*.gif,*.png,*.JPG,.JPEG,*.jpg}', GLOB_BRACE) as $image){    
    $image_data = exif_read_data($image);
    switch($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 8:
            $imageR = imagerotate($image,90,0);
            break;
        case 3:
            $imageR = imagerotate($image,180,0);
            break;
        case 6:
            $imageR = imagerotate($image,-90,0);
            break;
    }

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="tim.php?src='.$image.'&w=900&h=900&q=70&zc=3" rel="external">';
    echo '<img src="tim.php?src='.$image.'&w=200&h=200"/>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to perform the rotation only once and store the result in the server's filesystem or do you want to perform the rotaion always on-the-fly?

Comment: always on the fly would be best since I am allowing for upload of new images at any time.

Comment: In that case you could do the transforms in the script handling the upload.

Comment: `imagerotate` is a GD function. It doesn't (by its self) open an image, rotate and save it. You need to create a new GD resource with `$image`, then use `imagerotate`, then save it, then update the exif so that the rotation only happens once.

Comment: What would that look like... above you will see that I am actually creating new sizes of those images using timthumb, for the image src I am passing in the $image variable but I want to pass in the new rotated images instead of the old incorrect rotation of these images.